# Exception in library

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, python-asyncio

I'm working on a discord bot. I tried it on my pc and it works fine, But as I move it to a host I get this exception at start

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/container/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    import discord
  File "/home/container/discord/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .client import Client
  File "/home/container/discord/client.py", line 27, in <module>
    import asyncio
  File "/home/container/asyncio/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .base_events import *
  File "/home/container/asyncio/base_events.py", line 296
    future = tasks.async(future, loop=self)
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

As I traced it back I found out it's in asyncio library which is a built-in library.

I also tried to match the versions but it's same as my pc and latest

---

### Edit #1:

Server startup command

```
:/home/container$ if [[ -d .git ]] && [[ ${AUTO_UPDATE} == "1" ]]; then git pull; fi; if [[ ! -z ${PY_PACKAGES} ]]; then pip install -U --target /home/container/ ${PY_PACKAGES}; fi; if [[ -f /home/container/requirements.txt ]]; then pip install -U --target /home/container/ -r requirements.txt; fi; /usr/local/bin/python /home/container/${BOT_PY_FILE}
```

Requirments:

```
discord
discord.py
PyYAML
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this regards an error in a package on a host not controlled by the OP. I believe it is off topic.

Comment: @wwii It is not server fault since I'm running 2 other discord bots on their hosting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is because you have a folder `asyncio` in your root dir. In order to use `asyncio` you'll have to import it from build-in libs and not a directory.

Please make sure you are using python 3.4+ (recommended 3.8 as for today)

Comment: Server auto-install it when I want to start it... How can I prevent the server from installing that?

Comment: "server auto-install" does not create a folder "asyncio". 
Just remove the folder and use build-in functions

Comment: As I removed the asyncio folder and the requirments.txt (So it won't check it anymore) problem is fixed

Comment: glad to hear... happy gaming

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the same library which you downloaded them on your pc using pip install.

Comment: Read the last line: "I also tried to match the versions but it's same as my pc and latest"

Comment: asyncio lib is not installed.